# scp is giving timeout errors although ssh works fine

Tags: ssh, vps, scp, digital-ocean

I have a Digital Ocean droplet that I can ssh into just fine.  This is how I work on the server.  The other day I went to use scp and was given the following error;

`scp -r host@my_ip:/path/to/file .`
`ssh: connect to host my_ip port 22: Connection timed out`

Previously it worked with out a problem.  I have changed the ports in ssh_config and restarted the deamon on both the local and remote machines.  I have added firewall rules to the local machine and changed them when I changed the ports ssh is to use.

I still get the same error message.  Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: When you ssh into the box, do you privide a non-standard port via `-p XXX` ? If yes, you need to add that when scp'ing, try adding `-P XXX` to your scp command.

Comment: Thanks but I use hostname alises to login.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is MTU related 
try setting your client's network card mtu smaller for example

ifconfig enp10s0 mtu 1000
(linux)

Comment: after setting mtu for 1000 does it solved the problem? scp timeout can be due to other reasons?